# Custom module resolution in TypeScript + VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have the following project structure:

```
<PROJECT_FOLDER>
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── MyAwesomeComponent.tsx
│   ├── views
│   │   └── MyAwesomeView
│   │       └── index.tsx
│   ├── Application.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
├── webpack.config.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

and the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,

        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "src/*",
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Assume I have `react` in `node_modules` (and even `@types/react` installed). When I'm tryin to import somewhat, for example `import * as React from "react"` or `import MyComponent from "components/MyAwesomeComponent`, both imports are errorneous with message **"Cannot find module..."** and so on.

As I'm writing the import string, VSCode suggests me modules from `node_modules`, but doesn't suggest me folders from `src/*`.

Relative import still works, but this is the hell, you know.

I'm definitely new to TypeScript, but I'm doing things according to the "Module Resolution" TypeScript docs, and it doesn't work.

Highly appreciate any help here!

---

### Update

I have changed my `moduleResolution` to `node` and set the config shared by @Alserda (thank you for answer, but looks like I'm doing something wrong, because you config doesn't solve the problem). Then I run suggested `tsc --traceResolution`. It resolved all my imports as well, VSCode now resolving the `node_modules`, but still doesn't resolve my `components/MyAwesomeComponent`:[image]

---

### Update 2

Well, my `webpack.config.js` does already have corresponding modules
[image]

But I don't think that the problem is here, I even did not run `webpack-dev-server`, and I believe that VSCode doesn't use the `webpack.config.js` information to configure the project :)

---

### Update 3

Here is the output for the `components/MyAwesomeComponent` import:

```
======== Resolving module 'components/MyAwesomeComponent' from '/home/username/path/to/project/src/Application.tsx'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
'baseUrl' option is set to '/home/username/path/to/project/src', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'components/MyAwesomeComponent'.
Resolving module name 'components/MyAwesomeComponent' relative to base url '/home/username/path/to/project/src' - '/home/username/path/to/project/src/components/MyAwesomeComponent'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/username/path/to/project/src/components/MyAwesomeComponent', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File '/home/username/path/to/project/src/components/MyAwesomeComponent.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/username/path/to/project/src/components/MyAwesomeComponent.tsx' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name 'components/MyAwesomeComponent' was successfully resolved to '/home/username/path/to/project/src/components/MyAwesomeComponent.tsx'. ========
```

---

### Final update

VSCode did not enforce update project settings from my `tsconfig.json` even after `Reload TypeScript project`. I just restarted it, and everything works fine now! :)

Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Try `tsc` with `--traceResolution` to get some more information about what is happening.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I have updated my answer

Comment: Can you please search the `--traceResolution` output for `components/MyAwesomeComponent` and add the relevant output to the question so we can see how the resolution is failing?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Yes, updated the question :) As I said, the resolution with `tsc` does not fails now, it resolves everything successfully, but it still fails in the VSCode (VSCode says that it cannot resolve my modules, but it resolves `node_modules` now)

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question carefully enough.  VSCode should be using your tsconfig.json; I don't have any ideas about the discrepancy, and unfortunately I don't have any ideas for further debugging either, other than restarting VSCode if you haven't done that already.

Comment: "I just restarted it, and everything works fine now!" <- omg, THIS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have to add this key:

```
...
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
...
```

The `path`key that you are using is mainly for making TypeScript understand that your imports 'will work' for your Webpack configuration. Say you have an `alias` key in your Webpack configuration like:

```
alias: {
  core: resolve(__dirname, '../src/services/core'),
```

(and you have your `context` key on your `src` folder).

Then you should add a `path` key in your tsconfig like

```
    "paths": {
        "core/*": ["./services/core/*"],
```

(with your `src` folder as `baseURL`

I'm always using the following configuration for TypeScript & React.js. This has been working great for me for multiple projects.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es3",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strict": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "jsx": "react",

        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

And if you're using [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader), I also include this:

```
    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "useCache": true,
        "forceIsolatedModules": true
    }
```

Edit:

I think the import error is related to Webpack. Try setting the following in your Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
...
context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
resolve: {
  modules: ['src', 'node_modules']
...
```

Comment: Well, running the `tsc --p tsconfig.json` with your config and `--traceResolution` successfully resolves all imports (at least my own imports, did not check other, because there are a lot of em). VSCode TypeScript checker now resolves the `node_modules` (thanks to `moduleResolution: "node"`, I suppose), but still says that `components/MyAwesomeComponent` doesn't exist.

Comment: I have updated my answer too :) But I don't think that this is the point.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was that VSCode doesn't update config settings even after `Reload TypeScript project`. I just restarted it and everything works fine now, thank you!

Comment: I had a 'Have you tried restarting VSCode?' comment ready, but I forgot to press 'Add Comment'.. Glad that solved it. Good luck! TypeScript + React combo is great.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: `"include": [ "src/**/*" ]` did the trick for me. I had `"include": [ "src/*" ]` initially and was wondering why running `tsc` from the command line would work, while vscode would throw errors. Turns out my `tsc` run was a false positive, since it didn't even include the majority of my code base. Only found out about that when I used the `--traceResolution` flag and started grepping the result for the aliased imports I was troubleshooting.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like magic for us ! Can you explain what two wildcards mean and why do we need them ? Why can't I use just `src/*` ?

Comment: @mkpro double asterisk is a recursive search. It will match any file inside the specified folder. Generally speaking, if we using `src/*` - it will match only first-level files and folders, where `src/**/*` will match any file or folder of any level of deepness.

Comment: Oh wow! That `src/**/*` is an absolute godsend! Thank you!